# How to move right aside to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, position

I would like to know how to move a right aside/div to the bottom of a page using CSS or  javascript.  I know i can use grid or flexbox to stack items into a single column automatically when resizing the page but would like to have the ability to move the aside to the bottom when clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS to your div using JQuery.

Create a CSS class with the style and positing you need.

```
$("#DivID").addClass("ClassName");
```

[W3 Schools Help](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I was more looking for specific css to do this.  I'm working with Grid CSS however it doesn't work in IE.  Flex is my next option.  I'm not considering Bootstrap at this point.